# External NFC Reader for PC within Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

Has anyone had any success with using an External NFC reader in Unity. All the examples i can find are using Android NFC, however i'm doing a project on PC so i'm unable to use that obviously.

If anyone can point me in the right direction or has a solution that can help, it would be most appreciative.

Comment: PCs don't have the necessary hardware for NFC

Comment: You'll need to reference the documentation of the external reader. Perhaps using an HID interface to read from it.

Comment: I'll start digging for the documentation. I've already had a look around and haven't found much but i'll see what i can do. Thanks